# DataSet Scaler with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

This is a Python program that takes data from Quandl Databases and formats it for my Neural Network to Train.

The code works but I'm not so confident in my code styling conventions. If you would like to review this code with any styling suggestions on how to reformat the code (with respect to PEP8), feel free to review.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as dr
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
import random



class DataSet:
    '''
    Represents a formatted, scaled, and preprocessed dataset for the neural network to use
    '''
    def __init__(self,ticker,time_ahead):
        '''
        :param ticker- the symbol for the stock:
        :param time_ahead- the time ahead we want to predict:
        '''
        #Pandas dataframe to use for formatting the data
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.time_ahead = time_ahead
        #Pandas dataframe for formatting the validation data
        self.val_df = pd.DataFrame()
        #Sequence Length
        self.seq_len = time_ahead*5
        #List of Training Data and Prediction Set
        self.sequential_data = []
        self.prediction_set = []

    @staticmethod
    def __classifiy_target(current, future):
        '''
        Classifies the data set whether to be BUY (1) or SELL (0)
        :param current price:
        :param future price:
        :return: 1 or 0
        '''

        if float(future) > float(current):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def __get_data_from_quandl(self):
        '''
        Grab data from quandl database with api, from WIKI/Prices
        :return:
        '''
        try:
            #Grab Data of specified stock from WIKI table
            self.df = dr.get_data_quandl('WIKI/{}'.format(self.ticker), api_key='mauS86cm-z7iYixknxcz')
            #Convert index to datetime stamp (original format is date string)
            self.df.index = pd.to_datetime(self.df.index).astype(int) / 10 ** 9
            print(self.df.head())
        except Exception as e:
            raise ValueError('The Following Error has occured: {} \n Make sure \'API Key\' and \'Stock Ticker\' are valid'.format(e))

    def __shape_data(self):
        '''
        take full data and leave only our metrics: historical close & historical volume
        :return:
        '''
        self.df = self.df[['AdjClose', 'AdjVolume']]
        self.df.rename(columns={'AdjClose': 'Close', 'AdjVolume': 'Volume'}, inplace=True)
        print(self.df.head())

    def __add_target(self):
        '''         
        add target (y) column, for valiation training
        :return: 
        '''
        #shift current price *time_ahead* amount of spaces to make future price column
        self.df['Future'] = self.df['Close'].shift(-self.time_ahead)
        #classify wheter in the future we should buy or sell the stock
        self.df['Target'] = list(map(self.__classifiy_target, self.df['Close'], self.df['Future']))
        print(self.df.head())

    def __create_out_of_samples(self):
        '''
        Out of sample test set, take last %5 of the training set for validation
        :return:
        '''
        times = sorted(self.df.index.values)
        last_5pct = times[-int(0.05 * len(times))]
        #seprate validation data from stock data
        self.val_df = self.df[self.df.index >= last_5pct]
        self.df = self.df[self.df.index < last_5pct]

    def __scale_data(self, df):
        '''
        scale dataframe values to normalize the data
        :param df:
        :return:
        '''
        #in each column other than target (the answer)
        for col in df.columns:
            if col != 'Target':
                #change the numbers to the percent of change between two consecutive dates
                df[col] = df[col].pct_change()
                #drop any value that is null
                df.dropna(inplace=True)
                #use preprossesing from sklearn to scale values
                df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values)
        df.dropna(inplace=True)


    def __create_sequential_data(self, df):
        '''
        create the list of data in sequence
        :param df:
        :return:
        '''
        self.sequential_data = []
        #a queue for keeping sequences of prices, when we reach max, the deque pushes out the front and adds a new value in the back
        curr_days = deque(maxlen=self.seq_len)
        #iterate over all values of dataframe
        for i in df.values:
            # the -1 is for excluding the target column
            curr_days.append([n for n in i[:-1]])
            #when we reach the specified sequence length, add it to the list of sequences
            if len(curr_days) == self.seq_len:
                self.sequential_data.append([np.array(curr_days), i[-1]])
        #save the first value of the list == sequnece for the CURRENT price of the stock
        self.prediction_set = self.sequential_data[0]
        #shuffle the list
        random.shuffle(self.sequential_data)

    def __balance_data(self):
        '''
        balance the data so that the neural network wont just guess one value
        :return:
        '''
        buy_stock = []
        sell_stock = []

        #sort the data into two: buys and sells
        for seq, target in self.sequential_data:
            if target == 1:
                buy_stock.append([seq,target])
            elif target == 0:
                sell_stock.append([seq,target])
        #get the shorter length between the lists
        lower_len = min(len(buy_stock),len(sell_stock))

        print('Shortest list is {}'.format(lower_len))
        random.shuffle(buy_stock)
        random.shuffle(sell_stock)
        #cut the length of the longer list to equal the shorter one
        buys = buy_stock[:lower_len]
        sells = sell_stock[:lower_len]

        #combine the lists back to main list, and shuffle
        self.sequential_data = buys + sells
        random.shuffle(self.sequential_data)

    def __finalize_training_data(self):
        '''
        call the scaler and sequencer, and clean up the list of future column for the TRAINING DATA
        :return: X_train list, Y_train list
        '''
        self.df = self.df.drop('Future', 1)
        self.__scale_data(self.df)
        self.__create_sequential_data(self.df)
        self.__balance_data()

        X_Train = []
        Y_Train = []

        for seq, target in self.sequential_data:
            X_Train.append(seq)
            Y_Train.append(target)
        return np.array(X_Train), np.array(Y_Train)

    def __finalize_test_data(self):
        '''
        call the scaler and sequencer, and clean up the list of future column for the VALIDATION DATA
        :return:X_test list, Y_test list
        '''
        self.val_df = self.val_df.drop('Future',1)
        self.__scale_data(self.val_df)
        self.__create_sequential_data(self.val_df)

        X_Test = []
        Y_Test = []

        for seq, target in self.sequential_data:
            X_Test.append(seq)
            Y_Test.append(target)
        return np.array(X_Test), np.array(Y_Test)

    def pre_proccess_data(self):
        '''
        main function- puts evreything together and delivers the formatted data
        :return: x and y training and validation data, along with the prediction set
        '''
        #Call the private class methods
        self.__get_data_from_quandl()
        self.__shape_data()
        self.__add_target()
        self.__create_out_of_samples()

        #get training sets
        x_train, y_train = self.__finalize_training_data()
        x_test, y_test = self.__finalize_test_data()

        return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, self.prediction_set
```